# Add UIActivityIndicator to UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have seen a lot of explanation about this in other posts but nothing that actually works.

I have a uitableview that takes a few seconds to populate from an rss feed.  in viewdidload I want to start animating the indicator.  I want to end it when my data loads.

Does anyone have a solution for doing this through code and not through interface builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Three20 library: https://github.com/facebook/three20

It has Table View component that does what you need out of the box. I imagine it'll be a lot easier to integrate this than trying to recreate the whole thing from scratch